# Rails 3 Is there support of online editing and saving word documents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ms-word

Could someone know is there support with Rails of on-line editing and saving MS Word documents  (like a http://www.officelive.com/en-us/ or http://docs.google.com )?
Thanks

Comment: No. This is not something that Rails provides out of the box. It is not what Rails is made for.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer but no, there isn't.

Answer (score 1):

I think its been long time but now we have one thing which is made on ruby and node.js like google drive and one drive. If you still want you can have look at this. https://github.com/d4l3k/WebSync